# SQL Server - update table history

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Consider the following data sample from #myTempTwo

```
sno     |   name        |budget |NameTrim   |TravelCost|    Expense
1       |Local Travel   |123    |Travel     |246       |    NULL
2       |Global Travel  |123    |Travel     |246       |    NULL
3       |Local Expense  |12     |Expense    |NULL      |    24
4       |Curent Expense |12     |Expense    |NULL      |    24
```

Scenario where `TravelCost` or `Expense` is null update with a value. Let's say 1 for expenses and 2 for travelCost.

Now the said update:

```
update #myTempTwo 
 set TravelCost = '2' where TravelCost is null
 update #myTempTwo 
 set Expense = '1' where Expense is null
```

this will yield:

```
    sno     |   name        |budget |NameTrim   |TravelCost|    Expense
    1       |Local Travel   |123    |Travel     |246       |    1
    2       |Global Travel  |123    |Travel     |246       |    1
    3       |Local Expense  |12     |Expense    |2         |    24
    4       |Curent Expense |12     |Expense    |2         |    24
```

Can I somehow see the original data (from before running the update, without saving it in some other table. I'm looking for some 'undo' or 'view history' or some 'temp snapshot'? (Using sql server 2012)

If yes, how can I do it?

Comment: Make a database backup

Comment: And other than that? @GiorgiNakeuri

Comment: Why do you exclude "saving it in some other table" as an option? `SELECT * INTO #myTempTwo_backup FROM #myTempTwo` is really the easiest solution.

Comment: Well, imagine for a second you performed an update you didn't wanted to perform, you inserted some faulty value. And you didn't used a `#temp`, the backup is daily/weekly and you can't use that because in the meantime some other queries were performed and you can't go back. Is there something to be done? ps: I don't actually have a problem, I'm doing this as an excercise to understand more about the wonders of SQL

Comment: @CM2K, create a trigger and log old values. You can then do a undo step by step.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri , now that's an interesting approach. How would you do that for the example given? Never used one. Insert it as an answer, since this sounds like a great solution

Comment: @CM2K, ok I will provide it as an answer.

Comment: Check out CDC (Change Data Capture).
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627369.aspx,  This probably  wont work on temp tables, but since you are just investigating, its worth a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example with trigger and history table:

```
CREATE TABLE OriginaTable(ID INT IDENTITY, Price MONEY)
GO

CREATE TABLE HistoryTable(ID INT IDENTITY, OriginalID INT, Price MONEY, CreatedDate DATETIME)
GO

CREATE TRIGGER trOriginaTable ON OriginaTable
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  IF UPDATE(Price)
  BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.HistoryTable
                ( OriginalID, Price, CreatedDate )
                SELECT ID, Price, GETDATE() FROM Deleted
  END
END
GO

INSERT INTO OriginaTable VALUES(NULL)
GO

UPDATE dbo.OriginaTable SET Price = 100 WHERE ID = 1
UPDATE dbo.OriginaTable SET Price = 10 WHERE ID = 1
UPDATE dbo.OriginaTable SET Price = 200 WHERE ID = 1

SELECT * FROM dbo.HistoryTable
```

Output:

```
ID  OriginalID  Price   CreatedDate
1   1           NULL    2015-11-05 18:46:49.823
2   1           100.00  2015-11-05 18:46:49.830
3   1           10.00   2015-11-05 18:46:49.833
```

As you see history saves all old values.